# Object of type 'Mycart' is not JSON serializable in Django

Tags: json, django, serializable

I want to add dictionary(having models) datatype object to request.session
but getting "Object of type 'Mycart' is not JSON serializable in Django"

```
product_details = {}
for product in products_in_cart:
    product_details.update({product.id: 
    (product,request.POST['quantity'+str(product.product.id)])})  
request.session['product_details'] = product_details
```

I expect the dictionary updated in session but the actual output is "Object of type 'Mycart' is not JSON serializable in Django"

Comment: Can you provide the tracback? Right now it is unclear what raises the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the `product` which is the first parameter of your tuple inside of your dictionary. you need to serialize it before you can use it in your tuple like this:

```
 from django.core import serializers

 product_details = {}
 for product in products_in_cart:
     s_product = serializers.serialize("json", [product])
     product_details.update({product.id: 
    (s_product,request.POST['quantity'+str(product.id)])})  
     request.session['product_details'] = product_details
```

Comment: @vipinsharma If that was helpful and it fix your problem then you can mark my answer as accepted :)